# JavaScript getAttribute() method in image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing to drag and  drop the image in javascript. I gave some attributes in image. I am calling the attributes `("data-id")` on the name.

```
<img class="item" id="Img2" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Figen" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" data-id="20" />
        <img class="item" id="Img3" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Naz" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" data-id="30"/>
        <img class="item" id="Img4" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Test" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" data-id="40"/>
        <img class="item" id="Img5" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Huni" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" data-id="50"/>
        <img class="item" id="Img6" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/red&text=Mavi" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" data-id="60"/>
        <img class="item" id="Img0" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Can" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" data-id="90"/>
```

Now, When I drag and drop the images above , I want to catch (data-id) in the class side.Codes are true the class side but when ı try to drop the image , I dont catch the (data-id) in the javascript.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {

     ev.preventDefault();

}


function drag(ev) {

    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

}


function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

    var itemToMove = document.getElementById(data).getAttribute("data-id");
    ev.target.appendChild(itemToMove);
```

[image]

when I postback the images , ı want to see code behind .
[Return İdList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqwso.png)

it says "not found"

The codes are true in the class.

I call it here `Public Property idlist() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _idlist
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
            _idlist = value
        End Set
    End Property`

and return it , isnt there problem .

Comment: Please, can you explain you want do more clear?? the error i see in you code is the `text` parameter that has bee typed `Text`. also, you `itemToMove` variable is a text, so you cannot append it to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you meant, you want to go get the `data-id` attribute  and drop it somewhere.  you are trying to drop a text. `appendChild(x)` method require `x` to be childNode. Hence, you should convert the text into childNode.
you can do it as following.

```
        var itemToMove = document.getElementById(data).getAttribute("data-id");
       //convert itemToMove into a TextNode.
      itemToMove = document.createTextNode(itemToMove);
      //append it into the target
     ev.target.appendChild(itemToMove)
```

However, you should noticed that written `text` and `Text` in you data transfert type. They should be the same. 
Hope it helps

Comment: I edited it more clear for you , can you review again?

Comment: Check what you corrected. have tried what I proposed you as solution??

Comment: I tried I saw the numbers(data-id) , but I want to send this data to class side.I have to retain in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. I works fine with me.
[image]

Comment: its okey , but when I send the data with ajax to class more in , it gives a error.İf you want to see , ı can send all codes.

Comment: Excuse for late reply. you can send me the code ( or simply explain me what you really want to do)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369941/javascript-drag-and-drop-how-to-get-data-id-with-getattribute-when-dropped-a